# 1 Image URL saved on database (but different versions available on the main server): how to replace a letter on the fly to avoid image scaling?

Tags: php, smarty

this is the situation: i have a supplier who gives me 1 URL image only for the catalogue...for example the large version
that is: **http://www.domain.com/dev/1/1/08973911/l_08973911.jpg**
This image URL on database is saved into the field: **supplier_reference** ...
so i can call the img src with:

```
<img src="{$product.supplier_reference|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}" width="150" height="133" />
```

and all is ok 'cause it scales... but i don't want it to scale. 
Sometimes, as in this case, i don't need the large version but this kind of small 150x133...
the correct URL i need will be:
**http://www.domain.com/dev/1/1/08973911/s_08973911.jpg** that is the **s** version.
How can i do to replace only that letter for the URL taken from the DB?
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you are using [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/). If so, you can use Smarty's [replace](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.modifier.replace.tpl) variable modifier:

```
<img src="{$product.supplier_reference|replace:'/l_':'/s_'|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}" 
width="150" height="133" />
```

Comment: yes! it's smarty... :-) tomorrow i'll try and let you know. Thanks for now

Answer (score 1):

```
$url = preg_replace('#l(_\w+\.jpg)#', 's\1', $url);
```

Comment: It seems that the code is not pure PHP, so you cannot use preg_replace() in it.